# Laravel: New registered service provider in app doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, laravel, apache, lamp

The issue is this one:

I've been reading and trying the examples from Laravel's official documentation, particularly the Service Providers section:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/providers#the-bindings-and-singletons-properties

I've noticed here, when describing the usage of "The bindings And singletons Properties", that the text "ServerProvider::class" it's, in the page's example, set as a key twice, both in '$bindings' and '$singletons' arrays at the service provider properties.

I was wondering if this was correct, and I've tried in some Laravel project, this code (just for testing, defining all the tested interfaces and classes in the same file: 'NuevoServiceProvider.php', located in the same folder as the rest of Service Providers):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

interface ServerProvider{
    public function mostrarServidor();
}

interface DowntimeNotifier{
    public function notificar();
}

class  DigitalOceanServerProvider implements ServerProvider{
    public function mostrarServidor(){
        echo "Servidor Digital Ocean<br>";
    }
}

class  ServerToolsProvider implements ServerProvider{
    public function mostrarServidor(){
        echo "Herramientas del servidor<br>";
    }
}

class PingdomDowntimeNotifier implements DowntimeNotifier{
    public function notificar(){
        echo "Tiempo: 8ms<br>";
    }
}

class TestClass
{
    protected $value = 0;

    public function increase()
    {
        $this->value++;

    return $this->value;
    }
}


class NuevoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
     /**
     * All of the container bindings that should be registered.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $bindings = [
        ServerProvider::class => DigitalOceanServerProvider::class,
    ];
 
    /**
     * All of the container singletons that should be registered.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $singletons = [
        DowntimeNotifier::class => PingdomDowntimeNotifier::class,
        ServerProvider::class => ServerToolsProvider::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->singleton(
            ServerProvider::class,
            ServerToolsProvider::class
        );
        
        $this->app->singleton(
            'test1',
            TestClass::class
        );
    
        $this->app->bind(
            'test2',
            TestClass::class
        );
        error_log("Nuevo servicio register");
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        //
        error_log("Nuevo servicio boot");
    }
}
```

At my 'config/app.php', in the array 'providers', I've added:

```
...
App\Providers\NuevoServiceProvider::class,
...
```

In a route defined also just for testing, I've done:

```
Route::get('servidores', function (ServerProvider $servidor){
    $servidor->mostrarServidor();
});
```

So, when I hit 'localhost/.../servidores', I've got:

> Herramientas del servidor

I've tried to change the order of '$bindings' and '$singletons' at my new service provider file, but I've still got the same.

However, when I've tried to replicate these steps on another Laravel project, when I hit the correspondent route I've got:

> Class "ServerProvider" does not exist

In Tinker, I've got:

> >app('ServerProvider'); 
> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  Target class [ServerProvider] does not exist.

But when I do:

> > app('test1');
> = App\Providers\TestClass {#4147}

That work's fine.

Although I've also tried to bind 'ServerProvider' with the 'singleton' method instead that with the properties of the new provider, I'm still getting the same error.

I'm running the second Laravel project in an Apache server, while the first one just being run with 'php artisan serve'. I've tried to restart Apache service, but didn't worked.

Any idea of what's going on? I'm wondering what I'm missing or doing wrong.
I'm also wondering if the documentation example has sense, or it's just a mistake that 'ServerProvider::class' was twice written as an array key.

In my posted code, I've also tried code from an example of another website, but the issue is with the Laravel documentation example.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed my mistake. I should placed the line:

```
use App\Providers\ServerProvider;
```

At my route file.

Despite I've could solve this issue, I still have the doubt about the twice repeated 'ServerProvider::class' key, in both '$bindings' and '$singletons' arrays, at the documentation example.